# How can I write a JavaScript regular expression to allow only letters and numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I wish to allow both upper case and lower case.  I have tried

```
'k abBcdi #!129'.replace(/^[A-Za-z0-9]/g,'')
```

But it's not give me the correct answer

Comment: That pattern will remove all uppercase, lowercase, and numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also use [^0-9A-z] instead. It probably has little to no performance effect, but it is slightly shorter and prettier.

Edit:Per a comment above, are you trying to find all letters and numbers and replace them or remove everything that's not a letter and number?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use NOT operator (`^`) inside brackets:

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't explicitly need to use the not `^` operator, you could simply use a special character to identify all non-alphanumeric characters:

```
'k abBcdi #!129'.replace(/[\W]/g,'')
```

Or, given that `\W` allows the underscore (`_`) it might be preferred to use:

```
'k abBcdi #!129'.replace(/(\W+)|(_)/g,'')
```

References:

- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).